# Select indices in an array along an angle

Tags: python, arrays, geometry

I have an array of data, say a 10 x 10 array as shown below

```
A=array([[ 50, 385,  67, 445, 336, 305,  48, 419, 106,  39],
       [217, 188, 139,  64, 258, 340, 188,  18,  58, 278],
       [201,  43, 457, 196, 149, 289, 350,  86, 495, 448],
       [379, 376, 217, 124, 264,  69, 378, 296, 200, 416],
       [234,  65, 420,  44, 489, 451,  46, 216, 136,  97],
       [470, 162, 183, 480, 149, 482, 456, 294,  89, 337],
       [164, 335, 443, 305,  30, 381, 341, 331, 149, 261],
       [389, 160, 448, 304,  30, 280, 333, 360, 166, 300],
       [ 63, 346, 321, 229, 432, 129, 100, 217,  83, 196],
       [218,  33, 430, 237, 225, 391, 393, 344, 457,  82]])
```

If I randomly select the index of data point 149, and an angle of 45 degree for example and I want 5 data points, I want it to return the indexes of the 5 data points along that 45 degree line. As shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1pdK.png). My angles are in ranges of 45 degrees, i.e -45, -90, ..., 180. So I can have data around the selected index like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIYJh.png)

In the case of the example above, it should return the indexes of data points

```
[149, 451, 378, 86, 58]
```

Comment: How many angles value can you have, for example what would the output be for an angle value of 13?

Comment: My angles are in ranges of 45 degrees, that is -360, -315, -270, ..., 360

Comment: -369? I think that is not a valid angle value

Comment: 360, that was a typo

Comment: Angles are in this range -45, -90, ..., 180.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works: (use python 3.8 or newer):

```py
A=list([[ 50, 385,  67, 445, 336, 305,  48, 419, 106,  39],
       [217, 188, 139,  64, 258, 340, 188,  18,  58, 278],
       [201,  43, 457, 196, 149, 289, 350,  86, 495, 448],
       [379, 376, 217, 124, 264,  69, 378, 296, 200, 416],
       [234,  65, 420,  44, 489, 451,  46, 216, 136,  97],
       [470, 162, 183, 480, 149, 482, 456, 294,  89, 337],
       [164, 335, 443, 305,  30, 381, 341, 331, 149, 261],
       [389, 160, 448, 304,  30, 280, 333, 360, 166, 300],
       [ 63, 346, 321, 229, 432, 129, 100, 217,  83, 196],
       [218,  33, 430, 237, 225, 391, 393, 344, 457,  82]])
    
def where_is_each_datapoint(A):
    places = dict()
    for r_i , row in enumerate(A):
        for c_i , col in enumerate(row):
            if col in places.keys():
                places[col].append((r_i,c_i))
            else:
                places[col] = [(r_i,c_i)]
    return places

places = where_is_each_datapoint(A)

point = 149
angle = 45
number_of_datapoints = 5

def get_row_col_steps(angle):
    if angle in [360, -360]:
        return (0,1)
    elif angle in [315, -45]:
        return (1,1)
    elif angle in [270, -90]:
        return (1,0)
    elif angle in [225, -135]:
        return (1,-1)
    elif angle in [180, -180]:
        return (0,-1)
    elif angle in [135, -225]:
        return (-1,-1)
    elif angle in [90, -270]:
        return (-1,0)
    elif angle in [45, -315]:
        return (-1,1)
    return (0,0)

def find_datapoints(all_datapoints,point,angle,places,number_of_datapoints):
    result_datapoints = []
    place_of_point = places[point]
    row_step, col_step = get_row_col_steps(angle)
    for place in place_of_point:
        possible_result = []
        place_row = place[0]
        place_col = place[1]
        for i in range(number_of_datapoints):
            try:
                if (next_place_row := place_row + row_step*i) > 0 and (next_place_col := place_col + col_step*i) > 0:  # <--- This part should change for python versions lower than 3.8
                    possible_result.append(all_datapoints[next_place_row][next_place_col])
            except:
                break
        if len(possible_result) == number_of_datapoints:
            result_datapoints.append(possible_result)
    return result_datapoints

print(find_datapoints(A,point,angle,places,number_of_datapoints))
```

For python versions lower than 3.8:

```py
[...]
if place_row + row_step*i > 0 and place_col + col_step*i > 0:
    possible_result.append(all_datapoints[place_row + row_step*i][place_col + col_step*i])
[...]
```

Ouput:

```py
[[149, 451, 378, 86, 58]]
```

Explantion:

1. `where_is_each_datapoint()`: This function gets a `list` like similar to yours, and make a `dictionary` which it's `keys` are the `data points` and the `values` are the `coordinates`. There may be several `data points` with same value, for example in this list, there are three `149`s.
2. `get_row_col_steps()`: This function gets an `angle` and gives a pair of `(row_step, col_step)`, for example if it get `45` it will return `(-1,1)`.
3. `find_datapoints()`: This function returns all `data points`. Because it can be several `data points` with same value, so it can be several solutions for this, and it may be several set of `data points` for a specific `point` , `angle` ,and `number_of_datapoints`. for example if `point = 149` , `angle = 45` ,but `number_of_datapoints = 2`; there are `3` solutions: `[149, 340]`, `[149, 451]`, and `[149, 337]`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. I tried runing the code and got the error: ``File "<ipython-input-136-8476921a24d3>", line 57
    if (next_place_row := place_row + row_step*i) > 0 and (next_place_col := place_col + col_step*i) > 0:```   [SyntaxError: invalid syntax]

Comment: The syntax error is due to the ':=' operator

Comment: You have to have python 3.8 or newer. This feature if for version 3.8 and higher @YoosufAIshaaq

Comment: Hi @YoosufAIshaaq , I updated my answer. Please see the `For python versions lower than 3.8:` part in the answer.